# How to track users viewing habit

Tags: java, jms, java-ee-7

I need to keep a counter for couple of pages that each user visits.

Lets say I need to keep counter for page 1 and 2. UserA visits page 1 for 10 times therefore its counter should be 10, and 
userB visits page 1 for 5 times and page 2 for 7 times so user's counter for page 1 should be 5 and page 2 should be 7.

```
CounterTable ( shows number of times that each page has been visited by each user)

 Username Page Counter
 A         1    10
 B         1    5
 B         2    7
```

To achieve this, I have a table in DB which keep the usernames, page numbers and counters, every time that user visits a page the associated counter in db will be incremented.

My question is that, if I increment the required counter, every time that I want to retrieve the pages (1 or 2) the user needs to wait for the application to get the required record updated before visiting the page.

To avoid this, should I use JMS to send asynchronous requests to increment the counters in database? Another option, is to use ajax maybe to send async request to the server.

Is there any more efficient method to do it? if not which one is more efficient?

Comment: You could use an entity that keeps the counts current for display purposes and eventually updates the database. Since JPA implements a database cache, you could maintain an entity manager just for this purpose, updating the cache contents with each visit and trusting that JPA will eventually update the table.

Comment: @BobDalgleish wat do you mean by entity where should I keep it while user is browsing the website ? in cookie ?

Comment: Why you absolutely want to update the database in a asynchronous  way ? the required update is very simple and should be very quick with almost no effect on response time.except you have really a big quantity of data.What is the number of user ?).

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption that the counter is primarily for audit purposes instead of display purposes, another option may be to write an access log locally. I would recommend a standard format such as NCSA Common Log format which defines fields for URL, Method and user among others, but of course there are many other options available as well. You may even have such logging already built into your JavaEE Container or libraries, and just have to turn it on.

You would then use a tool like Splunk or LogStash, or others to pick up and aggregate this data outside of the request flow, and collect it from all of your servers. By keeping this raw access data around, you also can do further analysis, beyond just how many times did a particular user view a particular page, but also answering questions such as what times of days / days of the week are particular users active, do you have servers that seem to be getting more requests than others? Are particular pages popular around particular times? and many more.

Comment: As mentioned above, requirement is to keep the counters in the db. I do not get what you mean by common log!

Comment: NCSA Common Log Format - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format It's just a pretty standard way of writing entries for an access log (thereby easily consumable by many analytics packages). Could you expand on your requirement some? What is the ultimate purpose of tracking these counts? What are you doing with the information that requires it to be stored in a relational database? Also do you need to handle counts for requests for pages that don't exist?

Comment: Thanks, the requirement is simple, need to know how many times each user visited specific pages. Take eBay as an example, lets say eBay wants to know how many times each item has been viewed by each of its users.

Comment: The problem is, as currently setup, you would have to change your application code every time there is a new statistic to be gathered. You would also have no historical data. If you log all the details about an event, there are tools that can gather that and produce the views per page per user, and many other statistics. If you're talking a large site like eBay, not only would you use this data, and data from all pieces of your infrastructure, You'd likely also employ something like Google Analytics, where the client browser would callback and provide information to a central service.

Answer (score 1):

I think JMS will be a better option to go for. And the code should be well error handled in such a way that even if there is an issue with JMS or database, there should be ZERO impact on  page load and view. Reason being this error does not directly impact the functionality.

What I think the structure should be like:

The code piece where user page view is logged, this should actually send call to another function which is nothing but an executor, the job is pushed in that executor and that executor (Java Executor framework) will either send request to:

1. JMS
2. DB

Since it is already asynchronized, you can choose either two. But JMS will give a more abstract view and can be used across multiple projects / websites.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another method would be, using with `@Asynchronous` annotated methods or classes. I think the oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-async.htm#GKIDZ gives a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar request, I used log4j by extending and creating a new appender. In the appender, I used an asynchronous web request module (the log collector was on a remote location). In the application, the only thing I did is to create logger statements. I also created a log collector application, which captured these requests and executed the logic. The logic is up to you, either store to database or trash it. Since the logger statements execute asynchronous calls, they do not block the application.

Extending log4j is simple, just follow the link: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html